# Entire Car Chassis & Body Angle

Tags: mechanical-engineering

What is the name of the angle if I have larger wheels on the rear axles compared to the front, this would make the cars body and chassis not parralel to the road, unlike if the wheels were the same size.

In other words the body and chassis would be at an angle.

Does this angle have a certain technical name?

Comment: Hot rodders call(ed) it "rake".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed (unloaded), or typical angle of the floor of the car is usually referred to as *rake angle* and can be a combination of suspension geometry (including relative wheel/tyre diameters) and the shape of the floor itself.

It is particularly significant in cars which use ground effect to generate down-force where the floor, in conjunction with the front wing and a rear diffuser are designed to accelerate air under the floor of the car to create an area of low pressure by increasing the space under the floor and hence the cross sectional area of the flow from front to rear. Here the space enclosed between the floor and the road surface effectively forms an expanding nozzle although one of the technical challenges which limits this is to seal the gap between the floor and the road at the sides. There are examples where this has been achieved with flexible skirts (especially in early ground effect racing cars) although now it is more often achieved by precise control of airflow, especially vortices, off the front wing and other bodywork.

As well as the tyre diameter this can be controlled by the suspension geometry and spring/damper characteristics and it is perfectly possible to have a level, or even actively adjustable rake angle regardless of relative tyre diameters.  Indeed, cars with active suspension may adjust this angle in order to control the centre of pressure of downforce generated front to rear and/or to adjust the balance between downforce and drag. Some degree of control can also be achieved by flexible or movable sections of aerodynamic bodywork.

This may also be expressed in terms of front to rear *ride height* or *ground clearance* (especially in an off-road context).

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, automotive engineers borrow from the field of aviation to define vehicle rotation about the three major axes.  Using their terminology, the angle you refer to would be called "pitch".  In addition to larger-diameter rear tires, one could say a vehicle "pitches forward" under heavy braking.  The other axes are yaw (as if the car were on a turntable) and roll (the tilting experienced during fast cornering).